# A lower bound for the absolute curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

I have gotten stuck while trying to solve an exercise that requires me to find a lower bound for the absolute curvature.

Let $\gamma:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^3$. Suppose that there is $x_0 \in [a,b]$ such that $|\gamma(x)| \leq |\gamma(x_0)|$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Show that $|\frac{dT}{ds}| \geq \frac{1}{|\gamma(x_0)|}$.

Here $T$ denotes the unit tangent field $T=\frac{\gamma'}{|\gamma'|}$.
I am working with the following definitions

[image]

Using these definitions I get $\frac{dT}{ds}=\frac{T'}{|\gamma'|}$. I want to show that
$|\gamma(x_0)| |\frac{dT}{ds}| \geq 1$. We have

$$
|\gamma(x_0)| |\frac{dT}{ds}|
\geq |\gamma| |\frac{dT}{ds}| 
= |\gamma| |\frac{T'}{|\gamma'|}| 
=\frac{|\gamma|}{|\gamma'|} \frac{|T'|}{|T|}. 
$$

The next step would be to show that $\frac{|\gamma|}{|\gamma'|} \frac{|T'|}{|T|} \geq 1$. But I do not see why this would be true. Clearly both factors are bounded and attain their infimum as they are continous functions but this only yields the desired result if both infima are greater than or equal to 1.

\Edit: I think I have found a solution. Suppose w.l.o.g. that the curve is arclength-parametrized. The hypothesis implies that the curve lies inside a sphere of radius $|\gamma(x_0)|$ with center at the origin. So for $x \in [a,b]$ consider a circle centered at the origin with radius $|\gamma(x)|$ that touches $\gamma$ at $\gamma(x)$. Then the absolute curvature of this circle is $\frac{1}{|\gamma(x)|}$. This curvature satisfies $\frac{1}{|\gamma(x)|} \geq \frac{1}{|\gamma(x_0)|}$ and agrees with the curvature $|T'(x)|$ of $\gamma$. So $|T'(x)| \geq \frac{1}{|\gamma(x_0)|}$ which is the statement I wanted to prove.

Comment: are you sure it is $|\gamma (x_0)|$? It will not be $|\gamma '(x_0)|$ instead? Because the position of a point of a curve is completely unrelated to it curvature

Comment: @Masacroso The result is correct and quite well-known. Think about a curve trapped inside a circle/sphere centered at the origin. Polymorph: Since this is an abstract question, you may (and should) assume the curve is arclength parametrized to start with. Have you tried to use the hypothesis of the exercise?

Comment: The result is false as stated. For example, take $\gamma\colon [0,1]\to \mathbb R^3$ to be $\gamma(x) = (x,0,0)$, and $x_0=1$. Then $|\gamma(x)|$ takes a maximum value of $1$ at $x=x_0$, but $dT/ds\equiv 0$. You need to stipulate that $x_0\in (a,b)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin The hypothesis implies that the curve lies inside a sphere of radius $|\gamma(x_0)|$. I believe it is possible to use  this to  derive a solution that involves circles that touch the curve. I have added my ideas to the initial post.

Comment: @JackLee's point is a superb one. Your heuristic is a decent one, but is hard to justify in three dimensions (which circle exactly?) until you study surfaces and learn about normal curvatures. I would suggest actually using calculus and using what you know about functions at their (interior) maximum points.